# How to compare elements in a [[]]?

Tags: list, haskell

I am dealing with small program with Haskell. Probably the answer is really simple but I try and get no result.

So one of the part in my program is the list:

```
first = [(3,3),(4,6),(7,7),(5,43),(9,9),(32,1),(43,43) ..]
```

and according to that list I want to make new one with element that are equal in the `() =`:

```
result = [3,7,9,43, ..]
```

Comment: So where are you stuck in your attempts? Please note this site geared towards answering specific questions. Requests like "here's my assignment, help me out I have no idea where to start" are frowned upon.

Comment: I was trying something like this `result = [x | x <- (head first), x fst == x scd ]` take element and check the statement but is it not working. I am working with [[]] and I got the [] so this is a first problem, and I think the way that I am trying to 'iterate' is wrong

Comment: Well this is not a `[[]]`, but a `[(a,a)]`...

Comment: First, remove the `head` -- it's dangerous, and not even needed here. Second, why do you apply function `x` to argument `fst` ? That makes no sense, you want `fst x` instead.

Comment: and `snd` to obtain the second item.

Comment: Edit your attempt into your question! Then all those questions in the comments are not relevant for later visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you appear to have not made the most minimal amount of effort to solve this question by yourself, I will give you the answer because it is so trivial and because Haskell is a great language.

Create a function with this signature:

```
findIdentical :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Int]
```

It takes a list of tuples and returns a list of ints.

Implement it like this:

```
findIdentical [] = []
findIdentical ((a,b) : xs)
    | a == b = a : (findIdentical xs)
    | otherwise = findIdentical xs
```

As you can see, `findIdentical` is a recursive function that compares a tuple for equality between both items, and then adds it to the result list if there is found equality.

Comment: `findIdentical = filter (uncurry (==)) . map fst`

Comment: What is your point, that a problem has an infinite amount of possible solutions? To be honest I prefer my function as it is very explicit while yours uses 5 functions in 1 line. It does reduce 50% of the lines of code, which is nice.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Your solution does not even typecheck

Comment: @Glubus I prefer something like this: `findIdentical xs = map fst $ filter (\(a, b) -> a == b) xs`. Although the recursive solution is always clear and easy to read.

Comment: @RoadRunner Your function is also perfectly explicit, I might even prefer it actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for instance with list comprehension. We iterate over every tuple `f,s)` in `first`, so we write `(f,s) <- first` in the right side of the list comprehension, and need to filter on the fact that `f` and `s` are equal, so `f == s`. In that case we add `f` (or `s`) to the `result`. So:

```
result = [ f | (f,s) <- first, f == s ]
```

We can turn this into a function that takes as input a list of 2-tuples `[(a,a)]`, and compares these two elements, and returns a list `[a]`:

```
f :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [a]
f dat = [f | (f,s) <- dat, f == s ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to use the Prelude's [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function, which has the type definition:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

All you need to do is supply predicate on how to filter the elements in the list, and the list to filter. You can accomplish this easily below:

```
filterList :: (Eq a) => [(a, a)] -> [a]
filterList xs = [x | (x, y) <- filter (\(a, b) -> a == b) xs]
```

Which behaves as expected:

```
*Main> filterList [(3,3),(4,6),(7,7),(5,43),(9,9),(32,1),(43,43)]
[3,7,9,43]
```